# Write one xpath to check text present in two different html elements

Tags: html, xpath

I want to write xpath to check the text "You can save $45.34 when you buy two items together". But as you see below it is present in different html tags. How can I do that?

```
<p _ngcontent-c41 class="black-font">
    <strong _ngcontent-c41 class="ng-star-inserted">
        "You can save "
            <span -ngcontent-c41 class="dollar amount">$45.34</span>
        " when you buy two items together."
    </strong>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the text, you could write something like :

```
normalize-space(//p[@class="black-font"])
```

Output :

```
"You can save " $45.34 " when you buy two items together."
```

To check the presence of the text in Selenium, you could write something like :

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//strong[@_ngcontent-c41][contains(.,'You can save') and contains(.,'" when you buy two items together."')]")))
```

Imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```